# Rhino AST and Functions nested in variable

Tags: javascript, parsing, rhino, abstract-syntax-tree

I am just looking at the AST part of Rhino to parse a JS file to retrieve all the function names.
The issue I have is that the functions are all child elements of a Variable (Declaration or Initializer not sure which these both have the same type ints but you cannot cast a Declration to an Initializer).

So the script is thus:

```
  var myFuncs = {
       foo:function(){....}
       bar:function(){
          getFooBar:function(){
            var foobar = function(){};
            return foobar;
          }
       }
    }

 var somethingElse= {}
```

My question is how can I get a list of all functions that are contained in the myFuncs variable/object;

I have not seen very good documentation for Rhino AST maybe I am missing something somewhere but all I have is the Java Doc which is quite patchy in places.
If someone has a good link to a tutorial using Rhino AST I would appreciate it if the answer is not simple.

This is my parsing code

```
CompilerEnvirons compilerEnvirons = new CompilerEnvirons();
compilerEnvirons.setRecordingComments(true);
compilerEnvirons.setRecordingLocalJsDocComments(true);
compilerEnvirons.setStrictMode(true);

File scriptFile = new File("C:/myJsFile.js");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(scriptFile);
AstNode astNode = new Parser(compilerEnvirons).parse(fr, null, 1);
AstRoot astRoot = astNode.getAstRoot();
```

With the astRoot I have tried various get statements such as getSymbols() getStatements() and getFunctions() but these don't give me the functions I am trying to reach.

I have also tried to visit with a NodeVisitor but when looking for functions this gives me the only function that is in the doc that is **not** within a variable so nothing nested in a variable which is what I am looking for. If I visit variables I can find the VariableDeclaration/Initializers but then I cannot get the name of the variable to check I have the myFuncs var.
Really struggling to walk over this structure.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think I have got a little closer I can find all function() declarations but then I cannot find the naming foo: or bar: which is what I really need.

Answer (score 0):

Walk through the ASTNode, look for a *FunctionDeclaration* and use it's getName() to get the identifier.